# How do I put a div at top of another using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've built a html page using flexboxes. There are 1 main flex-container and it has 2 sides - left and right respectively. Now I need to put another div at top of these too, like this:
[image]

FlexContainer is the main class of these 3 children. The problem I've come accross is unavailability to make it work like this. I know how to do it with relative positioning, though, but I don't like this way. My current page looks like this:

```css
.flex-container 
{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.leftSide 
{
  padding-top:30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow:auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.rightSide
{
  padding-top:30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%; 
  overflow:auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

<div class="leftSide">

</div>

<div class="rightSide">

</div>

</div>
```

How do I put header_switch at the top position as shown in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrap the left/right and then add a top element.

The left/right wrapper gets `row` direction (default), and the main container gets `column`.

The main difference with a wrapper and `column` direction, compared to use `row` and simply wrap the items, is that you will better be able to dynamically control the filling of remaining height's.

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;        /*  added  */
}

.flex-container .middle {
  flex: 1;                       /*  added, fill remaining height  */
  display: flex;                 /*  added  */
}

.top {
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.rightSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="top">
    top
  </div>

  <div class="middle">

    <div class="leftSide">
      left
    </div>

    <div class="rightSide">
      right
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.flex-container 
{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-container div
{
   padding-top:30px;
   border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.top{
  flex: 100%;
}

.leftSide 
{
  flex: 1;
}

.rightSide
{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

<div class="top">
top
</div>

<div class="leftSide">
left
</div>

<div class="rightSide">
right
</div>

</div>
```

You just need to set `display: flex` attribute for the container.

1. use `flex: 100%` for the top item
2. user `flex: 1` for left and right items

Comment: Yep, nice simple and nice solution :)

Comment: @J.Nick Be aware though, and since you had `height: 100%;` on the container, with this solution you can't make neither top nor left/right dynamically take the remaining height of the container, so if you need that you'll have to go with my answer's solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flex-grow: 1` for the div `header_switch`.

Answer (score -2):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLeO8.png)try this

```
.container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height:100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    .header {
      height: 70px;
      flex:1;
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    .main {
      flex:1;
      display: flex;
      height:100vh;
      background-color: #aaa;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .child-right {
      flex:1;
      background: blue;
    }
    .child-left {
      flex:1;
      background: red;
    }
```

and then in your HTML wrap your divs these classes

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="child-left"></div>
      <div class="child-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I will be happy to explain this. here we have created a container div which is flex itself and uses full height and width of the view. Now we create its two children one which is used for header and another is main view. header view has its fix height and main view have a property of flex:1 which tells that it will use all the space available in window. further main contains two view which are left one and right one who also have property flex:1 which will divide themself equally in main.

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer